# Is it correct and natural to say "how much further are we to a place"?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct and natural to say *how much further are we to a place* meaning how many more miles do we have to cover to get to the place? For example:

> We've been driving for three hours. How much further are we to the town?

Comment: I have seen such sentences in novels. It seems pretty correct.

Comment: I think it is unnatural and does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use "are we" since you are not asking about "we" but about the remaining distance, which is an "it".

> How much further is it to the town.

You can ask "...are we" to mean "how much progress have we made (since the last time I checked)"  You can use that literally (of a journey) but it is more likely to be figurative.

> Jack, you've been designing the website.  When I spoke to you last week, you had some pencil sketches of the design.  How much further are you towards a completed design?

Comment: "How much further is it?" or "How near are we?"